# Add index exemptions to single field in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I've got a Firebase structure:
`collection > document1 > subcollection1 > document2`.
Document2 has two fields: *field1:Map* and *field2:Arr*.
When I try to save data to *field1* I get the error: *too many index entries for entity*. My object to save has 10k fields.

I tried adding index exemptions, but it didn't help. Maybe I did it wrong. What should be my collection ID (*subcollection1*?) and field path (*document2* or *document2.field2*?) in add exemption card in Firestore?

**Edit**

Answer is:

`collection ID:` *subcollection1*, and `field path:` *field1*

Answer (score 0):

By the time am answering this question, the [maximum number of index entries for a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#indexes) is `40,000`. This number is composed of the number of single-field index entries and the number of composite index entries. So most likely those combinations made you reach the limitation, so indeed the above error is thrown.

To avoid such a situation, you can simply divide the document into two documents, one that contains the map and one that contains the array.

**Edit:**

When it comes to adding Map fields inside a document and you're getting the above error, then please check:

- https://firebeast.dev/tips/too-many-index-entries-for-entity

Comment: My array is much smaller. In my case, map doesn't need indexing. Could you tell me, how to add exemptions correctly referring to my db structure?

Comment: Please check my updated answer. It's probably most likely it's about the maps, right?

Comment: Yes. Problem is with too big map. Array is saving correctly. I saw example from link. My problem is, that I don't understand, what is correct collection ID and field path in my case.

Comment: Yes, that's indeed the problem, you're using a Map that creates too many indexes. The collection ID is the ID of the collection to which the document that reached the limit belongs. While the field path is the name of the Map field. Is it ok now?

Comment: Did my answer and updated answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Not completly, but thanks. I solved the problem.

Comment: So can I help you with other information? Btw, nice question.